# Swift 2 to Swift 3 migration: Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, xcode8

I had a block of code parsing JSON from the youtube API. The JSON object received is stored in the dictionary and then a sub array of JSON objects items is stored in item. Xcode is giving me an error where it says: `"items" is an ambiguous reference to member subscript for JSON and i for item[i].`

I read through some posts on stack-overflow addressing similar issues where it said Swift 3 changed the type to `[String: AnyObject]` but that didn't work for me either.

```
    do
        {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
            //print(json)
            let item: Array<Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>> = json["items"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>>

            for i in 0 ..< item.count
            {
                let snippetDict = (item[i] as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                // Initialize a new dictionary and store the data of interest.
                var desiredVideoDict = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()

                desiredVideoDict["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
                desiredVideoDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["url"]
                desiredVideoDict["videoID"] = (snippetDict["resourceId"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["videoId"]

                // Append the desiredPlaylistItemDataDict dictionary to the videos array.
                //self.videosArray.append(desiredPlaylistItemDataDict)

                // Reload the tableview.
                self.tblVideos.reloadData()
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The standard JSON dictionary has the type `[String:Any]` in Swift 3.

I recommend to use a type alias for better legibility.

```
typealias JSONObject = [String:Any]
```

Now you can write your code this way (I changed also the `for` loop syntax)

```
do
{
  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! JSONObject
  //print(json)
  let items  = json["items"] as! Array<JSONObject>

  for item in items
  {
    let snippetDict = item["snippet"] as! JSONObject

    // Initialize a new dictionary and store the data of interest.
    var desiredVideoDict = JSONObject()

    desiredVideoDict["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
    desiredVideoDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDict["thumbnails"] as! JSONObject)["default"] as! JSONObject)["url"]
    desiredVideoDict["videoID"] = (snippetDict["resourceId"] as! JSONObject)["videoId"]

    // Append the desiredPlaylistItemDataDict dictionary to the videos array.
    //self.videosArray.append(desiredPlaylistItemDataDict)

    // Reload the tableview.

  }
  self.tblVideos.reloadData()
...
```

`mutableContainers` is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    do
    {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data , options: .mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        //print(json)
        let item = json["items"] as! Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>

        for i in 0 ..< item.count
        {
            let snippetDict = item[i]["snippet"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            // Initialize a new dictionary and store the data of interest.
            var desiredVideoDict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()

            desiredVideoDict["title"] = snippetDict["title"]
            desiredVideoDict["thumbnail"] = ((snippetDict["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["default"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["url"]
            desiredVideoDict["videoID"] = (snippetDict["resourceId"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["videoId"]

            // Reload the tableview.
            self.tblVideos.reloadData()
        }
    }catch{
        print("parse error")
    }
```

Comment: I think explaining the issue might help OP to understand what he did wrong.